# Can we have more than one view controller in SplitViewController ?

Tags: ipad, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I am just starting with iPad App development. I want to use splitViewController in my app. I have gone through various tutorials and references about the same. In all of those I mainly see all we have is one masterViewController and one detailViewController. Content of detailView are loaded based on row selected in masterViewController. 
     my question is it possible to have different in an app viewcontrollers and those will be loaded on the click on respective row selection in masterViewController. If So should I have to initialized splitviewController in appdelegate only one of those or is there any other way to do this ? Please help me out.

Regards,
Sumit

Comment: Yes, you can have different controllers.

Comment: can you tell me how to do that or atleast direct me to any resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think It's what you are looking for : [it's a sample of code made by Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MultipleDetailViews/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009775)

> The application uses a split view controller with a table view controller as the root view controller. When you make a selection in the table view, a new view controller is created and set as the split view controller's second view controller.

Do not hesitate to ask for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot this is exactly what I was looking for. I wonder how I missed it on apple documentation but still thanks.